# How do I render a page in Node.JS with hogan-express

Tags: node.js, express, hogan.js

How do I render a page in node (using a router) which just passes a value to the template engine for me to use?

So for instance (this is the real code):

```
var apiRouter = express.Router();

 apiRouter.get('/myPosts', function(req, res){
    userPostsModel.findOne({'profileID':req.session.facebookProfileId}, function(err, userPosts) {
            if(userPosts) {
                res.json({
                    posts       :   userPosts.posts
            });
            } else {
                console.log('You do not have any posts');
            }
        })
})
```

And the template engine part (html file):

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Posts</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p><a href="/post?id={{posts.[0].postID}}">Post 1</a></p>
    <p><a href="/post?id={{posts.[1].postID}}">Post 2</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I am expecting this to render the page but instead, I am getting this (on the webpage):

```
{"posts":["12345667"]}
```

For my template engine, I am using 'hogan-express', as below:

```
app.engine('html', require('hogan-express'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

I know the res.json may be wrong here but I am not getting anywhere with this. The documentation for node and the routers is all over the place!

Comment: Which express plugins/modules are you trying to use to for templating?

Comment: Do you mean this: 
    var apiRouter = express.Router();

Comment: No, I'm guessing the problem is that you haven't set one? See [this guide](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html).

Comment: [This](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) seems like a logical starting point.

Comment: You're calling res.json which sends json data to client. Instead use `res.render('template-name', { posts:userPosts.posts});`

Comment: @Molda - that did it mate! How do I make your comment an answer? And thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: @ShayanKhan you can't, don't worry about it, I'm glad I could help

Comment: @Molda - thanks again man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Molda has answered in the comments, below, it should be like this:

```
res.render('template-name', { posts:userPosts.posts});
```

Tried it and worked for me.